# Count of products where sum of sales for particular product is higher than 2% of total sales - Power BI - DAX Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have facts tables with sales

[image]

I would like to create measure that counts number of products where sum of sales for particular product is higher than 2% of total sales.
For example:
1. sum of sales for 'ProductKey' 310 is 5000.
2. sum of sales for 'ProductKey' 346 is 2000.
3. 2% of sum of total sales is 3000.
Product 310 would be included in count product 346 wouldn't be included in count.
How would I write such measure?
I've tried to created something like this:

```
Big Sales =  
var SalesTotal = CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]))    
var twoperceSalesAmount =
CALCULATE (SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]), ALL( fact_InternetSales )) * 0.02
return
CALCULATE (COUNT(fact_InternetSales[ProductKey]),
FILTER (fact_InternetSales, SalesTotal - twoperceSalesAmount > 0))
```

Thansk

Kind regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also solution with SUMX works:

```
Big Sales SUMX = 
SUMX(VALUES(fact_InternetSales[ProductKey]),
IF(CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]))> 
CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]),ALL(fact_InternetSales))*0.02,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

The pseudoalgorithm is:
1. Calculate threshold
2. Consider only product with sales above threshold
3. Count number of products

```
        Big Sales:=
        var _threshold = CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]),ALL(fact_InternetSales))*0.02
        var _productlist =
        FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
        fact_InternetSales,
    fact_InternetSales[ProductKey),
"productsales",CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]))),
        [productsales]>_threshold)
        RETURN
        Countrows(_productlist)
```

If it is very slow web can optimize it.

Comment: Thanks Seymour. I'll check and I will let you know. I'm new to DAX and Power BI and it looks like you have good understanding of the subject. Are there any good online resources that you can recommend (blogs, youtube or online courses)?

Comment: There are an infinite amount of resource but my core ones are sqlbi.com, dax.guide, stackoverflow and practice.

Comment: You're right there are a lot resources, but not many with structured knowledge/guides. I currently use sqlbi.com and I try to practice as much as I can. dax.guide/ looks like good reference. Thanks!

Comment: Dax.guide is developed by sqlbi. Also check the books of marco russo and alberto ferrari

Comment: I will check the books. Thanks again!

Comment: If I solved your problem you can accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I checked the formula and it doesn't work.. possibly it's just the matter of closing brakets in right place. I tried to add them in few places, but it didn't work. Would you be able to check? Also, why did you use ADDCOLUMNS and SUMMARIZE? Thanks.

Comment: updated. Summarize performs a group by and addcolumns allow to calculate measures for each of the group. I suggest you check our dax.guide/summarize and dax.guide/addcolumns

Comment: I still get an error: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value." Thanks for additional explanation on the functions used.

Comment: It works. There was just square bracket missing.Big Sales:=
        var _threshold = CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]),ALL(fact_InternetSales))*0.02
        var _productlist =
        FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
        fact_InternetSales,
    fact_InternetSales[ProductKey]),
"productsales",CALCULATE(SUM(fact_InternetSales[SalesAmount]))),
        [productsales]>_threshold)
        RETURN
        Countrows(_productlist)